# Error rendering Councillors Online web part: [The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.]

Tags: wcf

I am implementing a WCF based solution and all was working fine until I started to process larger quantities of data.

The Solution worked well in DEV where we added large quantities of daata when we restored the site to QA we got this error . Error rendering Councillors Online web part: [The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.]

Can anyone propose a solution to this problem?

Thank you

My WCF web.config looks as follows :

========================================================

Answer (score 1):

This error can also come if you WCF Code return error -- **Object reference not set to an** **instance of an object**

As you can track through Fiddler

{"Detail":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

As you can also user Log to treas it out